# i want to redirect from one application to another application and send data through headers in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I'm trying to achieve the following:

I want to redirect from one application to another external application and send data through headers. and response should not come it should just redirect.

For eg :

WebApplication 1 :

```
    public ActionResult RedirectPage(string firstName,string lastName)
    {
       var url = "http://localhost:64603/";

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        request.Headers.Add("firstName", firstName);

        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        return new RedirectResult(url);
     }
```

Web Application 2 :

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (Request.Headers["firstName"] != null)
        {
            string ss = Request.Headers["firstName"].ToString();

        }
        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

        return View();
    }
```

So, my requirement is the page should be redirected from WebApplication1 to WebApplication2 and data should be send through headers.